# Growing tomato's and other plants inside

Tags: indoors, tomatoes, broccoli

I've always started the garden season late and I want to change that! I figured I could start seedlings now  growing them as indoor plants until April even though it's a little early to start inside.

I don't have nearly enough window space with natural sunlight for the plants that are growing to receive enough sunlight on top of there not being a full day's worth of sunlight. I don't have money for a green house and I'm not sure where to start with indoor lighting? Could I make a mini green house with plastic totes?

I'm growing tomatoes, some sunflowers, and broccoli. They look like they need more sunlight.L Also this is not where they are normally placed. I have cats that can get to them when they are not by the window.
[image]

Comment: Could you add something about your climate? From the title and description I'm little confused. Do you want just to growh seedling, so that you can harvest earlier tomatoes (which would be then outside), right? (Or harvest tomatoes growth inside? Seedlings have much less sun requirement. For plastic greenhouse: we need more info about climate (and snow)

Comment: What is the question?